# How would the Politburo respond to Project A119?

Tags: space, alternate-history, nuclear

In 1958 the United States Air Force considered a mission to detonate a nuclear device on the surface of the Moon. The endeavour was framed as a booster to American public morale in the wake of the Sputnik shock, as well as a field test of nuclear weaponry in a novel environment (with implications far beyond the battlefield).

Needlessly to say, they did not go ahead with this plan or you would already know about it.

What would have been the Soviet response if this actually happened?

Comment: The real question is, supposing that the American imperialists did detonate an atomic bomb  on the Moon, *how would the peace-loving Soviet Union find out?* Would the devious Americans forewarn the stalwart Soviet astronomers to look closely at a certain point at a certain time?

Comment: @AlexP, I hope you'll forgive me for parlaying your comment into an answer.

Comment: How would they get the nuke to the moon, if they did not have advanced rockets? If they had a rocket that could get a nuke to the moon, they would have one that could get a satellite into space. What would be the purpose, then, of 'making a statement'?

Comment: @AlexP since the main point of such an act would be as a publicly visible demonstration of power/capability to achieve "strategic PR" goals, forewarning Soviets and the rest of the would would obviously be part of that. In order to serve as "booster to American public morale" it would have to be pre-announced to American public so it can't be secret; just as Soviets wanted to ensure that radio amateurs worldwide can monitor signals from the Sputnik so that their assertion of space launch would be undeniable.

Answer (score 5):

**Nothing**

@AlexP has a good point. It's a human failing to assume all of the resources of "now" were or could have been available "then." There were no observational satellites (Sputnik 1 was only 1957), few observatories, and NASA was only one year old. The first ICBM was 1957 and the first lunar probe to touch the moon (curiously, the Soviet Luna 2) was in 1959.  America was actually behind the curve when Sputnik went into orbit.

And this is AlexP's point: the technology to see the fraction-of-a-second flash and relatively (compared to the moon as a whole) small damage area or the very-quickly-dispersed dust cloud (no atmosphere, low gravity) would require the Soviets to be watching the moon at the moment the bomb hit — basically requiring the U.S. to notify the Soviets (and the world) of the event before it happens.

But, let's assume that America developed lunar-capable space travel (unmanned payload) by 1959... what would happen?

*Scenario #1*

Condition: America was magically able to keep the Russians from knowing about America's space program.

I honestly don't know if a nuclear warhead is bigger or smaller than the Soviet Luna 2 - but either way, we're assuming the U.S. space program was further along than it was (by 4-6 years). Could the U.S. have kept that a secret?

I believe it is unbelievable unless there's a substantial difference in total technology between the two countries — in which case Russia isn't a superpower and their only response to a nuke on the moon is nothing.

*Scenario #2*

Condition: The U.S. and Soviet Russia are stealing each other's stuff just like they actually did.

This is believable, but in this case there's a better-than-average chance that Russia would know about the program before it launched. Not the details, mind you, but putting anything on the moon in 1959 would have been a big deal involving lots of engineers and big companies and it's hard to keep everything a secret. Russian response would be to land their own bomb on the moon — preferably before the U.S. did, but as soon thereafter as possible.

Note that in reality, it would have been the U.S. who was stealing secrets from the Russians (and we probably did). Note that we wouldn't be alone in that, if I remember history correctly, it wasn't until the Russians stole ball bearing tech from the U.S. that their ICBMs could be usefully accurate (not that an ICBM needs too much accuracy, but if you were aiming for Washington D.C. and hit the Florida keys....). So, I'm holding to this story.

*Scenario #3*

Condition: The Soviets are nearly as technologically capable but were caught by surprise.

This would lead to the proverbial World War III, followed soon after by zombies and handsome Australians driving V12 Interceptors. In this case the overwhelming technical advantage would be seen as too much of a first-strike capability. Of course, America would know that and not drop the bomb to avoid WWIII.

And that last bit is really important. Many if not most of everybody's missile/nuclear tests were as much to keep countries apprised of the testing country's status ("See! We're just a bit better than you! Don't mess with us!") as to actually test anything. *Détente* was a very big deal and eventually rested on the concept of Mutually Assured Destruction (MAD).

The idea that either country was willing to simply start a nuclear war is, if I remember my history correctly, frankly false. Military men certainly wanted to use the bombs ("a weapon unused is a useless weapon") but the politicians knew perfectly well what the consequences of their actions would be. Who wanted to be remembered as a worse genocidal maniac than Hitler (who died a scant 15ish years before)?

And what good is a glow-in-the-dark nation that can't be settled for who knows how long or the crippled world-wide economy that results from it? The two countries wanted *influence* and most of the militaristic dancing they did on a big scale was to keep the other country in balance (remember, it was a time of wars-by-proxy).

**Conclusion**

As I write this, I realize that your question is missing a LOT of information and probably ought to be closed until provided. What is the specific technological capabilities of both countries in 1959? Is either country willing to actually start a nuclear war? Have the politics of the two countries changed at all? How has the advance of technology changed the populations of the two countries? Etc.

The easiest solution is to move 1969 back to 1959... but everything else moves back with it, meaning nothing at all changes other than the date.  Moving just a chunk of something back to 1959 has considerable consequences on your world that would require a book to explain.

But, TL;DR, other than spurring the Soviets to greater efforts in both espionage and science — nothing would happen and history would play out little different than it did.

Comment: Aliens put the nuke on the moon in order to help the Americans.

Comment: +1 for "handsome Australians driving V-8 Interceptors"...

Comment: @JBh You are wrong to assume that it was impossible for the Americans to send anything to the moon before 1969. I remember watching a live broadcast from the Moon as an unmanned US lunar probe got closer and closer to the lunar surface.  The USSR sent back a photo of the far side of the Moon as early as 1959, and the USA had rockets almost as powerful. Remember that a soft landing was not required to land an atomic bomb on the Moon and detonate the bomb.

Comment: @JustinThymetheSecond I'm in with that! It explains everything, considering the enormous favor they owed us for hiding their intergalactic kegger near Roswell in '47!

Comment: @M.A.Golding, I did 30 seconds worth of Google searches on that because I was sure there was something before or during the Mercury program, but couldn't remember it and couldn't bring it up. To that end, you're correct. I'll modify my answer. Thanks!

Comment: The first ICBM was Russia's R-7 in 1957. The entire purpose of the space race was to sanitize and mask the ICBM nuke program. But hitting the moon with a nuke was child's play compared to Russia taking a picture of the back side of the moon with a film camera, developing the film in space automatically, and then scanning it with a cathode ray onto a photomultiplier then beaming it to earth. In 1959, before the transistor. THAT made a statement. Hitting the moon with a nuke just somehow wouldn't top it. Ho-hum so what. Russia could drop a nuke on New York and take a picture of it from space.

Comment: @JustinThymetheSecond, that's what I've been unsuccessfully trying to explain.  "THAT made a statement." That's why nuking the moon wouldn't have really changed anything. It's just another statement. What would Russia have done? Nuked the moon to prove they could do it, too... but nothing would have really changed. This was all gamesmanship - that was the real "war."  And what a LOT of people today don't realize is that kind of gamesmanship is still going strong - it's just taken more economic forms.

Comment: I am not arguing against your position. I made pretty much that same statement in a comment to the question. What I am doing is clarifying the facts behind and supporting the statement that it would be futile. But if it would have won an election, hey, I can see the Americans doing it. The statement would not be directed at the Russians however, it would be directed at the American electorate. The Russians would have laughed at the attempt and made diplomatic hay about the war mongering Americans. Russians 10 America 0. This time it is China that is winning.

Answer (score 3):

- **Public displays of outrage**
  Whatever else, Soviet spokespeople would decry the wanton destruction on an extraplanetary body by the 'capitalist warmongers.'
- **No OST?**
  The Outer Space Treaty was still a decade in the future, but the precedent might scuttle all attempts in that regard.
- **Militarization of space**
  Imagine it is the Cuban Missile Crisis and the generals tell the President that the Soviets have a nuclear bombardment system in orbit that could attack the US from any direction, at any time.

Comment: Modern internet-isms aren't very helpful here. 

Comment: @JBH Your objection to #1 doesn't make sense, because the question asks about the response on the Soviet side, not the US general public

Comment: The 1950s term would have been "fellow traveler" for a relatively neutral term, but yes, McCarthyism curbed that quite a bit.

Comment: The "public display of outrage" is the response of the Soviet Union through their multitude of propaganda arms.

Comment: @JBH but it's not *their* government they'd be complaining about.

Comment: @ChrisH having obviously screwed up a whole series of comments, let's delete them and start over. The 50's - anywhere in the world - were not a period of public protest. The Soviets would all too likely write scathing remarks in *Pravda,* but actual public outrage? In a country that regularly suppressed public comment of all forms for all reasons? I remember the cold war. I can't even imagine the Soviets successfully faking it. That simply wasn't the nature of the world at the time no matter who was complaining about whom.

Answer (score 1):

Short Answer:

That project was technically feasible.  An atomic warhead could have been detonated on the Moon by the USA as earlier as 1959.  The risk of failure would have been great in those days, including the risk of a launch failure and atmospheric contamination.  The danger of launch failure caused by the USSR and the USA to cancel projects to detonate warheads on the Moon. The Soviets would not have been particularly alarmed by a USA lunar detonation.

Long Answer:

> Project A119, also known as A Study of Lunar Research Flights, was a top-secret plan developed in 1958 by the United States Air Force. The aim of the project was to detonate a nuclear bomb on the Moon, which would help in answering some of the mysteries in planetary astronomy and astrogeology. If the explosive device detonated on the surface, not in a lunar crater, the flash of explosive light would have been faintly visible to people on Earth with their naked eye, a show of force resulting in a possible boosting of domestic morale in the capabilities of the United States, a boost that was needed after the Soviet Union took an early lead in the Space Race and was also working on a similar project.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Project_A119[1](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Project_A119)

> In 1949, the Armour Research Foundation (ARF), based at the Illinois Institute of Technology, began studying the effects of nuclear explosions on the environment. These studies continued until 1962.[2](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Project_A119#Research) In May 1958, ARF began covertly researching the potential consequences of a nuclear explosion on the Moon. The main objective of the program, which ran under the auspices of the United States Air Force, which had initially proposed it, was to cause a nuclear explosion that would be visible from Earth. It was hoped that such a display would boost the morale of the American people.[3](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Project_A119#Cancellation)
>
> At the time of the project's conception, newspapers were reporting a rumor that the Soviet Union was planning to detonate a hydrogen bomb on the Moon. According to press reports in late 1957, an anonymous source had divulged to a United States Secret Service agent that the Soviets planned to commemorate the anniversary of the October Revolution by causing a nuclear explosion on the Moon to coincide with a lunar eclipse on 7 November. News reports of the rumored launch included mention of targeting the dark side of the terminator—Project A119 would also consider this boundary as the target for an explosion. It was also reported that a failure to hit the Moon would likely result in the missile returning to Earth.[4](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Project_A119#Evidence_of_the_Soviet_project)
>
> A ten-member team led by Leonard Reiffel was assembled at the Illinois Institute of Technology in Chicago to study the potential visibility of the explosion, benefits to science, and implications for the lunar surface. Among the members of the research team were astronomer Gerard Kuiper and his doctoral student Carl Sagan, who was responsible for the mathematical projection of the expansion of a dust cloud in space around the Moon, an essential element in determining its visibility from Earth.[3](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_lunar_probes#1958%E2%80%931960)[6](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_lunar_probes#1962%E2%80%931965)
>
> Scientists initially considered using a hydrogen bomb for the project, but the United States Air Force vetoed this idea due to the weight of such a device, as it would be too heavy to be propelled by the missile which would have been used.[7](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_lunar_probes#1966%E2%80%931967) It was then decided to use a W25 warhead, a small, lightweight warhead with a relatively low 1.7 kiloton yield.[5](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_lunar_probes#1958%E2%80%931960) By contrast, the Little Boy bomb dropped on the Japanese city of Hiroshima in 1945 had a yield of 13–18 kilotons.[8](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/W25_(nuclear_warhead)) The W25 would be carried by a rocket toward the shadowed side of the Moon where it would detonate on impact. The dust cloud resulting from the explosion would be lit by the Sun and therefore visible from Earth.[5](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_lunar_probes#1962%E2%80%931965) According to Reiffel, the Air Force's progress in the development of intercontinental ballistic missiles would have made such a launch feasible by 1959.[9](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pioneer_0)

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Project_A119#Research[2](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Project_A119#Research)

> The project was eventually canceled by the Air Force in January 1959, seemingly out of fear of a negative public reaction and the risk to the population should anything have gone wrong with the launch. Another factor, cited by project leader Leonard Reiffel, was the possible implications of the nuclear fallout for future lunar research projects and colonization.[7](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pioneer_0)

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Project_A119#Cancellation[3](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Project_A119#Cancellation)

> Later reports in the 2010s show that a corresponding Soviet project did indeed exist, although the only official documents on the project presently found began in 1958,[10](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Luna_1) not the 1957 date of the "anonymous" source whose rumors initiated the US project, and the official Soviet plan similarly differs from the scenario reported in the press. Started in January 1958, it was part of a series of proposals under the codename "E". Project E-1 entailed plans to reach the Moon, while projects E-2 and E-3 involved sending a probe around the far side of the Moon to take a series of photographs of its surface. The final stage of the project, E-4, was to be a nuclear strike on the Moon as a display of force. As with the American plan, the E series of projects was canceled while still in its planning stages due to concerns regarding the safety and reliability of the launch vehicle.[11](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pioneer_P-1)

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Project_A119#Evidence_of_the_Soviet_project[4](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Project_A119#Evidence_of_the_Soviet_project)

Both the US and USSR projects were canceled by fear of a launch accident, not because it was calculated the explosion would not be visible from Earth.  It was possible that professionals and amateurs could see and film the pre-announced explosion though telescopes on Earth, and apparently it was calculated that the dust cloud raised by the explosion would be visible from Earth through telescopes and could be filmed.

The first attempts to send unmanned probes to the Moon by the USA and the USSR were in 1958.  All seven were failures due to launch vehicle failures.

In January 1959 the Soviet Luna-1 flew by the Moon, though it was probably intended to impact on it.  In March 2004 the US Pioneer 4 flew by the Moon and entered orbit around the Sun, in  September Luna-2 was the first successful impact on the Moon, in October Luna 3 passed the moon and sent back pictures of the Lunar farside.

There were many failed lunar probes in this period.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_lunar_probes#1958%E2%80%931960[5](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_lunar_probes#1958%E2%80%931960)

In 1962 the US Ranger 4 hit the Lunar far side.  In 1964 Ranger 6 impacted on the Moon.  In 1964 to 1965 Ranger 7, 8, & 9 sent pictures before impacting on the Moon, the Ranger 9 pictures were broadcast live.  And the Soviet Zond-3 flew past the Moon.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_lunar_probes#1962%E2%80%931965[6](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_lunar_probes#1962%E2%80%931965)

In 1966 Luna 9 had the first soft landing on the Moon and sent the first pictures from the surface, while Luna 10 was the first probe in Lunar orbit around the Moon.  Later landers in 1966 were Surveyor 1 and Luna 13, and later orbiters were Luna  11 & Luna 12, along with Lunar Orbiter 1 and Lunar Orbiter 2.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_lunar_probes#1966%E2%80%931967[7](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_lunar_probes#1966%E2%80%931967)

In short, by 1958 both the USA and the USSR had missiles capable of sending space probes to the distance to the Moon, and thus of sending probes to impact the Moon.  But the reliability of the launch vehicles left much to be desired in those days, especially when carrying atomic bombs in peacetime.  And there was possibility that the warhead might miss the Moon or land in the wrong position for visibility from Earth.

Project A119 planned to detonate a W25 warhead.

> The W25 is 17.4 inches (44 cm) in diameter and 26.6 inches (68 cm) long, with a reported weight of 218-221 pounds (98.8 - 100.2 kg) .[3](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Project_A119#Cancellation)

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/W25_(nuclear_warhead)[8](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/W25_(nuclear_warhead))

Pioneer 0, the first probe launched toward the Moon, weighed only 83.8 pounds.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pioneer_0[9](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pioneer_0)

The Soviet Luna E-1 No. 1 launched in 1958 weighed 361 kilograms or 795.8 pounds.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Luna_E-1_No.1[12](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Luna_E-1_No.1)

Luna 1 in 1959, the first probe to reach the vicinity of the Moon, weighed 361.3 kilograms or 797 pounds.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Luna_1[10](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Luna_1)

Luna 2, the first probe to impact on the Moon in 1959, weighed 390.2 kilograms or 860.24 pounds.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Luna_2[13](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Luna_2)

The failed Pioneer P-1 launched in 1959 was the first US lunar probe that weighed more than enough to carry a W25 warhead, at 168 kilograms or 370 pounds.  It was launched by an Atlas-C.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pioneer_P-1[11](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pioneer_P-1)

So the USSR launched probes to the Moon as early as 1958 with at least as much mass as was necessary for an atomic warhead, while the USA launched probes to the Moon with more than enough mass for an atomic warhead as early as 1959.

Thus Project A119 was technically feasible.  The USA could have detonated a nuclear warhead on the Moon as early as 1959. And that explosion could have been detected on Earth. However, there would have been a high risk of the warhead missing the target and detonating where it would not be visible from Earth, or missing the Moon entirely, causing humiliation when the scheduled explosion didn't take place, and also considerable risk of a launch accident and radioactive contamination on Earth.

As rockets became more and more reliable, and the risk of failure decreased, public fear of atmospheric radioactivity became greater, and the USA set a goal of a manned Moon landing.

Since the Soviets were considering a similar project and cancelled it for the same reasons as the USA, they would not have considered a US nuclear explosion on the Moon to be more evil than their own project, except in so far as any action taken for the glory of the USA would be considered more evil than the same action for the glory of the USSR.

Though the Soviets might have made propaganda over such a militaristic use of space, they wouldn't have believed their own propaganda enough to start a nuclear holocaust over it.u